# How to pull a file from a server using scp?

Tags: scp

I am on machine A and want to pull a file from machine B.

```
A$ scp <myuserid>@hostB:<path of file in B> .
```

it says that:

```
scp: <path of file in B>: No such file or directory
```

But on machine B, this file exists in this path.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Is this the exact format of the command you ran? Or was there a file name after the ':'?

Comment: I think, the edit is cunfusing as there seems to be virtually no difference between the question and [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22503/318461). According to [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22502/how-to-pull-a-file-from-a-server-using-scp#comment30438_22503), the error was because of relative vs absolute path.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You didn't specify any file: you have to add the file (with path) after the colon:

```
A$ scp <myuserid>@hostB:/absolutepath/file .
```

or

```
A$ scp <myuserid>@hostB:relativepath/file .
```

for a path relative to your home directory.

If you don't specify a different user (i.e., the user on A and B are the same) you don't need the `@`

```
A$ scp hostB:/path/file .
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting in the question, but maybe your answer is still valid. The problem might come from a confusion between absolute and relative (to home) paths.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez now that I see the edited answer I understand. It seemed a strange question :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ scp username@remoteip:remote_location_file /location/where/you/save
```

*Just as a note:* This only works when you copy file. if you want to copy a directory use

```
$ scp -r username@remoteip:remote_location_directory /location/where/you/save
```

We already saw the recursive option in the second command. This and a further selection of options you may use on your demand are listed [from the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

- `-r`
  Recursively copy entire directories.
- `-P port`
  Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host. Note that this option is written with a capital "P", because -p is already reserved for preserving the times and modes of the file in rcp.
- `-p`
  Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.
- `-v`

  Verbose mode. Causes scp and ssh to print debugging messages about their progress. This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.

Comment: The OP asked for copying a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 2):

use proper scp path

```
scp ssh://user@hostname/tmp/foo.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify either a file path that is relative to your home directory, or an absolute file path. For example, if `foo.txt` is in a directory called `docs` under your home directory and `bar.txt` is in `/var/tmp`, you can do

```
scp username@host.example.com:docs/foo.txt .
scp username@host.example.com:/var/tmp/bar.txt .
```

Note that if the file name contains characters that are special to the remote shell (typically whitespace or `` !"#$&'*;<>?[\]^`{|}~ ``), you need to escape them for the remote shell in addition to escaping them for the local shell. For example, if the file is called `foo bar.txt` and is in your home directory:

```
scp username@host.example.com:'foo\ bar.txt' .
```

If you have difficulties with files containing punctuation characters, try using `sftp` instead of `scp` to transfer them. Or use an even more convenient method, if you can use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/): mount the remote machine's filesystem using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), and then use ordinary file manipulation commands.

```
mkdir host.example.com
sshfs username@host.example.com:/ host.example.com
cp host.example.com/path/to/file .
```

Answer (score 1):

One can SCP both way easily if one has the DMZ user and Password
You are at your local machine:
From DMZ to your local linux machine (pull). Means copy `abc.text` inside `folder2` to your current logged-in PWD.

```
scp user@111111:folder1/folder2/abc.txt .
```

It will ask for password

thats all

Now you want to send a folder will subfolders and files from your local machine to DMZ:

```
usr@localmachine:~/abc/defs>  scp -r folder/ usr@111111:vkrishna/docker/
```

again password will be asked

`:` is the root folder of the remote machine and vkrishna is a folder there & again docker subfolder.
Locally defs folder has a folder called `folder` that we want to completely transfer.

Like `/abc/defs/folder`